# When the linear operator attains its maximum on a convex set

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f$ be a non zero continuous linear functional on a Banach space $X$. i.e.
$$f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ is linear and bounded.
Let $E$ be any non empty closed convex set of $X$ such that $$sup_{x\in E} |f(x)|$$ is attained. Then show that the supremum is attained at some extreme point of E.

Now if the assumption includes that the set $E$ is also compact then the supremum should be attaind (by the extreme value theorem) further by Krein- Milman theorem we can guarantee that it's attained at some extreme point.

But what about my question ? 
Is there any resource or book to find the proof ?

Comment: What is your question? When linear functionals attain maxima on convex subsets?

Comment: @s.harp sorry I edit the question. The question is to show that if the supremum attained on a convex set then it must attain at some extreme point

Comment: This strikes me as false. What if $X = \mathbb R$ and $f$ is constant?

Comment: @MeesdeVries The constant function isn't a linear function.

Comment: @Demophilus: But there is one linear, constant function. To get a slightly more difficult counterexample, consider $E = (-\infty,0] \times \mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^2$ and $f(x,y) = x$.

Comment: @gerw X here is Banach space

Comment: @SaraSuradi: Of course. And $X = \mathbb R^2$ is a Banach space.

Comment: @gerw also here the absolute value of supremum is not finite

Comment: Indeed, I missed the absolute value under the supremum. However, you could modify the example to $E = \{0\} \times \mathbb R$. Then, the supremum is $0$, but $E$ does not have any extreme points.

Comment: Maybe it should be interesting to add the hypothesis that $f$ is not identically zero. Otherwise the example of @gerw is a counterexample.

Comment: @Pozz the statement is true and I need a proof. You are right I should add this to the hypothesis.

Comment: @Pozz $\lbrace 1 \rbrace \times R$ is a counterexample for the linear functional $(x, y) \mapsto x$ on $R^2$, that is not trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement as given is not true. Take
$$
E = [0,1] \times \mathbb R
$$
and
$$
f(x,y)=x.
$$
Then the supremum is attained on the line $\{1\}\times \mathbb R$. However $E$ has not extreme point at all.

You have to exclude by assumption that the minimum of $f$ is attained on a line, as lines do not tend to have extreme points.